# Xamarin.forms ImageSource.FromFile doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm using Xam.Plugin.Media to take a picture .

```
 var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions()
        {
            Directory = "attachments",
            Name = fileName,
            CompressionQuality = 35
        });
        cam.Source = ImageSource.FromFile(file.Path);
```

above code does work !

file path is (file.Path):

```
/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/F3997E36-78EB-41AF-A37F-FC794BAF30EC/Documents/attachments/13c8ac4e57734a36bded2c2694e27495.jpg
```

but this code does not show picture in an Image control

```
var q = "/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/F3997E36-78EB-41AF-A37F-FC794BAF30EC/Documents/attachments/13c8ac4e57734a36bded2c2694e27495.jpg"  


 cam.Source = ImageSource.FromFile(q);
```

Answer (score 1):

On iOS, this is the way to load file you saved before. This is because the system regenerate UDID every time the app relaunch.

```
public Stream LoadSampleStream(string filename) {
    try
    {
        var documentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
        var filePath = Path.Combine(documentsPath, "Sample", filename);
        return new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I was having this problem using Xamarin forms Media Plugin `CrossMedia` which only returns the full path of the image that as stated above changes on startup, to overcome this I had to split the returned path string and get the filename from that and then use the above method to get the file stream.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save photo in gallery. When your user takes a photo it will still store temporary data, but also if needed make a copy to the public gallery

```
var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new StoreCameraMediaOptions
{
    SaveToAlbum = true
});
```

**Get the public album path**

```
var aPpath = file.AlbumPath;
```

**Get private path**

```
var path = file.Path;
```

Comment: I thought I could save in the app document folder and don’t need to put it in gallery